# insert a string into a List<String>

Tags: c#

I have the following-

```
public Class A
{
   public int a;
   public List<String> list;
}

public class B
{
   public int a;
   public string b;
}

A instanceofA;
B someB = new B()
{
  a = 1,
  b = "SomeString"
};
instanceofA= new A()
{
   a = someB.a,
   list = new List(){B}
};
return instanceofA;
```

The reason why i am converting string to `List<String>` is to pass it on to the UI layer and render it as drop down menu.

How to get the `string b` to the `List<String>` variable?
`B.ToList()` converts `B` into a character array.

Comment: @khargoosh : you cannot do this operation `A.list.add(B.b)` ; because `b` is not a static field

Comment: @khargoosh: if then you have to access it from the instance not from the class

Comment: @un-lucky I think this is another case of class name and instance name confusion (on my part). I intended `instanceofA.list.add(someB.b)`

Comment: Where is the code with the both instances is located? It is within a method?

Comment: Why you can't just -> instanceofA= new A() { a=someB.a, list= new List(){someB.b}};  And sorry but your code is really ugly, have to draw it on a paper to understand it :) please try to use more descriprive variable names, and no need to do anything in initializers, in fact I rareley see people use those at all...

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to put the `b`-property of your `B`-class into a list? Then you need the `b`-member to be added to the list, not your instance of `B`.

```
A instanceofA;
B someB= new B()
{
    a=1,
    b="SomeString"
};
instanceofA = new A()
{
    a=someB.a,
    list = new List<string> {someB.b }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the string member `b` to the list, not the entire class instance of `B` (which is not a `string`, because it is a `B`).

```
public Class A
{
    public int a;
    public List<String> list = new List<String>();
}

public Class B
{
    public int a;
    public string b;
}

public A someMethod()
{
    B someB = new B()
    {
        a=1,
        b="SomeString"
    };

    A instanceofA = new A();
    instanceofA.a = someB.a;
    instanceofA.list.add(someB.b);

    return instanceofA;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this(This question is not clear)

```
public class A{            
    public A()
    {
        this.list=new List<string>();
    }

    public List<String> list;
}
```

then `A.list.Add();`

If you wants add b to A list

```
public class A{
    public List<B> BList;
}
```

`A.BList.Add();`